# Given (A => B) => C , B, prove C with resolution method

Tags: proof-verification

So with the premises 
$(A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow C$ 
$B$

It is easy to prove $C$ in the Fitch method, as in the proof below
[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIynp.png)

Therefore I should be able to prove it using a resolution proof 
$(A \Rightarrow B) \Rightarrow C$ 
$\neg (A \Rightarrow B) \lor C$ 
$\neg (\neg A \lor B) \lor C$ 
$(\neg \neg A \land \neg B) \lor C$ 
$(A \land \neg B) \lor C$ 
$(A \lor C) \land (\neg B \lor C)$ 
1. $\{A,C\}$ 
2. $\{\neg B, C\}$ 
3. $\{B\}$ 
4. $\{\neg C\}$ 
5. $\{A\}$         1, 4 
6. $\{C\}$   2, 3 
7. $\{\}$ 4, 6 

So we're left with: 
$\{A\}$ 
$\{\}$

But there is no way to get rid of the $A$. What am I doing wrong? Or is the empty set mean we've proved it even though the $A$ is still there?

Comment: The proof you link to does _not_ prove $C$ from $(A\to B)\to C$, but from $(A\to B)\to C$ _and_ $B$.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say. I added line breaks for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I get it. I was just learning how this works.

I thought you had to resolve out everything, but really you just have to reach any contradiction that leads to an empty set. So by resolving C and not C and getting an empty set I have proved it. This is based on what I learned at this link:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-825-techniques-in-artificial-intelligence-sma-5504-fall-2002/lecture-notes/Lecture7FinalPart1.pdf